# LaTeX no me pone por defecto Figura, sino Fig

Tags: latex

En mi documento de LaTeX no se por qué a la hora de poner `\caption` directamente me pone Fig. en vez de Figura, se supone que al poner `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`. Ya sale por defecto Figura, también he probado con

```latex
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura }
```

y nada.

Comment: Quién sabe como insertes tus figuras. Yo lo hacía así:
\documentclass[...]{...}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{p1/image1.png}
    \caption{Icono de Control de pagos}
    %\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La sintaxis

```latex
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
```

**antes** (no despues)

```latex
\begin{document}
```

está bien solo sin

```latex
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
```

En cambio, si usas `babel`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering\includegraphics[width=10cm]{picture.png}
  \caption{Caption.}
  \label{fig:fig_one}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Lo siento pero solo hablo italiano y utilicé el traductor de Google :)

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar el paquete **caption** cambiando el parámetro *figurename*

```
\usepackage[figurename=Figura]{caption}
```